# Jest – How to mock non-default exports from modules?

Tags: unit-testing, react-native, mocking, jestjs

I am trying to mock `NativeModules` from `react-native`, but I can't find a way to only mock that class, and not the entire `react-native` module.

Basically, in my production code I do this:

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native'
const { MyCustomNativeModule } = NativeModules
```

In my tests, I want to rewrite `MyCustomNativeModule`. At the moment the only way I have found is to mock the entire `react-native` module like this:

```
// /__mocks__/react-native.js

module.exports = {
  NativeModules: {
    MyCustomNativeModule: {
      dismiss: () => {},
    },
  },
}
```

But that breaks all the other `react-native` functions. I saw that often people use methods like `jest.mock('NativeModules', () => ... )` but that really doesn't seem to be working!

Answer (score 5):

Here is the solution using `jest.mock` to mock `react-native` module manually.

In order to keep it simple, I simulate `react-native` module. You can use real `react-native` to replace the simulated one.

The file structure is:

```sh
.
├── index.spec.ts
├── index.ts
└── react-native.ts
```

Simulated `react-native` module:

`react-native.ts`:

```js
const NativeModules = {
  MyCustomNativeModule: {
    dismiss: () => {
      // original implementation
      return 'real data';
    }
  }
};

export { NativeModules };
```

`index.ts`, assume you import and use `react-native` module in this file:

```js
import { NativeModules } from './react-native';

export function main() {
  return NativeModules.MyCustomNativeModule.dismiss();
}
```

Unit test, `index.spec.ts`:

```js
import { main } from './';
import { NativeModules } from './react-native';

jest.mock('./react-native', () => {
  return {
    NativeModules: {
      MyCustomNativeModule: {
        dismiss: jest.fn()
      }
    }
  };
});

describe('main', () => {
  it('should mock react-native correctly', () => {
    const mockedData = 'mocked data';
    (NativeModules.MyCustomNativeModule.dismiss as jest.MockedFunction<
      typeof NativeModules.MyCustomNativeModule.dismiss
    >).mockReturnValueOnce(mockedData);

    const actualValue = main();
    expect(actualValue).toBe(mockedData);
    expect(NativeModules.MyCustomNativeModule.dismiss).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/54393006/index.spec.ts
  main
    ✓ should mock react-native correctly (19ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.096s
```

Here is the completed demo: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/54393006

Comment: This sort of setup only worked for me with Babel, as in [this example](https://github.com/thawkin3/jest-module-mocking-demo/). Without Babel, [this example setup](https://github.com/connorjburton/js-ts-jest-esm-mock/) got the job done. [GH issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/10025).

Answer (score -2):

what about this: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks

**class**

```
// sound-player.js
 export default class SoundPlayer {
   constructor() {
    this.foo = 'bar';
 }

  playSoundFile(fileName) {
   console.log('Playing sound file ' + fileName);
 }
}
```

**mocking with jest.mock( )**

```
import SoundPlayer from './sound-player';
const mockPlaySoundFile = jest.fn();
jest.mock('./sound-player', () => {
   return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
       return {playSoundFile: mockPlaySoundFile};
    });
  });
```

**UPDATE**

What about this way:

```
function mockFunctions() {
  const original = require.requireActual('../myModule');
  return {
    ...original, //Pass down all the exported objects
    test: jest.fn(() => {console.log('I didnt call the original')}),
    someFnIWantToCurry: {console.log('I will curry the original') return jest.fn((...args) => original.someFnIWantToCurry(...args)}),
  }
jest.mock('../myModule', () => mockFunctions());
const storage = require.requireMock('../myModule');
```

see: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/936#issuecomment-265074320

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it completely replaces the `react-native` module, instead of the `{ NativeModules }` from that module

Comment: Changed The Answer above