# Jest - mocking non-default imported function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I need to mock an imported function in a React application (created using create-react-app) with Jest. I tried to do what is shown in the docs and in other threads (e.g. here: [Jest – How to mock non-default exports from modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54393006/jest-how-to-mock-non-default-exports-from-modules)), but it doesn't work. Currently my project looks like this:

**calls getOne.js**

```
import {getOne} from "../../Services/articleService";

export const a = async function () {
    return getOne("article1");
};
```

**articleService.js**

```
export const getOne = async function (id) {
    return;
};
```

**testss.test.js**

```
import {ArticleTypes} from "../../Data/articleTypes";
import {getOne} from "../../Services/articleService";
import {a} from "./calls getOne";

jest.mock("../../Services/articleService", () => {
    return {
        getOne: jest.fn().mockImplementation(async (id) => {
            const articles = {
                article1: {
                    title: "Some valid title",
                    description: "Some valid description",
                    type: /*ArticleTypes.General*/"a"
                }
            };

            return Promise.resolve(articles[id]);
        })
    };
});

const mockedGetOne = async (id) => {
    const articles = {
        article1: {
            title: "Some valid title",
            description: "Some valid description",
            type: ArticleTypes.General
        }
    };

    return Promise.resolve(articles[id]);
};

beforeAll(() => {
    getOne.mockImplementation(mockedGetOne);
});

test("calls getOne", async () => {
    const res = await a();

    expect(getOne).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(res).not.toBeUndefined();
});
```

I have currently commented out ArticleTypes in the mock in the factory function used in jest.mock. I need to use them but I cannot use imported files inside the factory function. I just wanted to test if mocking would work there, but it does not work anywhere.

Why can't I mock the imports? Am I missing something? Do I need some additional configuration I don't know about?

Comment: Are you getting any errors while running your tests or does it just not work as expected? If there is an error, please share the error message as well. Also, couldn't understand the need for 2 mockImplementations of the `getOne` method.

Comment: Thank you, but I figured it out. For some reason, the mocks didn't work in the beforeAll and the jest.mock, but they worked in a beforeEach. I don't know why, though.

Comment: Quick point abt the testing strategy you are using here. You should ideally have separate test files for your modules and test individual functionality. So maybe add a separate test file for `articleService.js` to test the `getOne` method and a separate one for `calls getOne.js` which will assert that `getOne` gets called with the correct parameters. Not saying what you're doing is wrong but this can get a bit difficult in a more complex file if you try to test methods that are being called from within your source file.

Comment: Actually, I wasn't testing for the correct parameters to be called but in my real code, it calls getOne in the useEffect hook and that is what I was testing - that the component works correctly - and so I had to mock getOne to avoid it fetching a request from the actual server.